# Checkmarx: User input from the Params element...flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated

Tags: asp.net, checkmarx

I am taking a query string parameter, which is an encrypted identifier to an image, immediately using HtmlEncode, and then decrypting the value.

```
itemUrn = Utilities.Decrypt(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Request.Params["Item_Urn"]));
```

When Checkmax scan runs it complains about the element’s value then flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated. Specifically:

> Method Page_Load at line 64 of Somepage.aspx.cs gets user input from the Params element. This element’s value then flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated, and is eventually used in an HTTP response header in renderFile at line 149 of Somepage.aspx.cs. This may enable an HTTP Response Splitting attack, in certain older versions that do not mitigate this attack.

I am not sure what else beside using HtmlEncode and working with an encrypted that I can do. The value is coming from a web service call from a trusted internal source. If that encrypted value from the query string parameters cannot be decrypted then it would just end up an empty string.

Comment: You probably want to add the actual name of the result (probably Response Splitting) and maybe even more code to show the path to the header.  It is hard to give advice with so little code.  HtmlEncode may not be enough since when you decrypt the value, it may contain CR/LF thus the response splitting problem.  Even with a trusted source, emitting back a parameter value in the header can allow for some interesting ways to trick people into divulging sensitive data.